# How does this org.redisson.api.RExpirable.expireAt(long timestamp)?

Tags: redis, redisson

I need to know how

```
boolean org.redisson.api.RExpirable.expireAt(long timestamp)
```

in

```
org.redisson.api.RMap<K, V>
```

works ?

For eg; I create a bucket named **ABC** and add a key-value pair **key1** - **value1** . 
And I invoke the above method. 
So does this mean, my **key1**-**value2** will be removed from **ABC** bucket or the entire
 **ABC** will be removed after expiry-time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RExpirable.expireAt` method expires entire `RMap` object at defined time. If you looking for expiration per Map entry then `RMapCache` should be used instead.